# Neural Network data normalization

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, normalization

I'm currently training a neural network with tanh activation function (basic backpropagation without weight decay, momentum or any other improvements) to map an arbitrary function. The training data is within the interval (-1,1).

My training approach is as follows:

1. Splitting data into two parts (training and validation data).
2. Feeding the whole training data to the network (with weight update).
3. Feeding the validation data (without weight update) and calculate the MSE of all validation entries.
4. Repeat (starting at 2) until validation MSE at t-1 is almost equal to MSE at t.

I've tried to normalize the data using

```
f(x)=(x-mean)/std_deviation
```

but the MSE on the validation data is not getting below approximately 1.49. Without the normalization process, it reaches 0.005. Does someone has an explanation for this or an hind on improving my training procedure and data normalization?

Comment: A couple of questions: How many inputs/features do you have? When you normalize, are you normalizing against all features together or separately? As in do you find the mean for each feature and subtract that for each sample, or the mean for all features subtracted across each sample.

Comment: I'm experimenting with the feature count and hence the inputs, the example above is with 4 inputs, 3 hidden units and one output. The whole sample is approximately 900. 600 for training and 300 for validation. The normalization is done by calculating the std deviation and mean of the whole sample. In fact your second option:) Maybe it's helpful: The inputs and targets are a subset of training data. I train the net by defining a sequence of n elements, starting at index 0. I feet the subset from 0 to n-1 and use n as target. Afterwards, I continue with n to n+n-1 and so on.

Comment: do you normalize **feature-wise**? or **sample-wise**? do you normalize dependent variable as well (output)?

Comment: I normalize the whole sample, so sample-wise. No, I don't normalize the outputs but the target/expected values because they are part of the sample. Should I normalize the outputs before I calculate the MSE?